# Finding the index of the first word starting with a given alphabet form a alphabetically sorted list

Tags: sorting, search, arraylist

Based on the current implementation, I will get an arraylist which contains some 1000 unique names in the alphabetically sorted order(A-Z or Z-A) from some source.

I need to find the index of the first word starting with a given alphabet.

So to be more precise, when I select an alphabet, for eg. "M", it should give me the index of the first occurrence of the word starting in "M" form the sorted list.

And that way I should be able to find the index of all the first words starting in each of the 26 alphabets.

Please help me find a solution which doesn't compromise on the speed.

---

**UPDATE:**

Actually after getting the 1000 unique names, the sorting is also done by one of my logics.
If this can be done while doing the sorting itself, I can avoid the reiteration on the list after sorting to find the indices for the alphabets.

Is that possible?

Thanks,
Sen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I came up with my own solution for this.

```
package test.binarySearch;

import java.util.Random;

/**
 *
 * Binary search to find the index of the first starting in an alphabet 
 * 
 * @author Navaneeth Sen <navaneeth.sen@multichoice.co.za>
 */
class SortedWordArray
{

    private final String[] a;                 // ref to array a
    private int nElems;               // number of data items

    public SortedWordArray(int max)          // constructor
    {
        a = new String[max];             // create array
        nElems = 0;
    }

    public int size()
    {
        return nElems;
    }

    public int find(String searchKey)
    {
        return recFind(searchKey, 0, nElems - 1);
    }

    String array = null;
    int arrayIndex = 0;

    private int recFind(String searchKey, int lowerBound,
            int upperBound)
    {
        int curIn;

        curIn = (lowerBound + upperBound) / 2;
        if (a[curIn].startsWith(searchKey))
        {
            array = a[curIn];
            if ((curIn == 0) || !a[curIn - 1].startsWith(searchKey))
            {
                return curIn;              // found it
            }
            else
            {
                return recFind(searchKey, lowerBound, curIn - 1);
            }
        }
        else if (lowerBound > upperBound)
        {
            return -1;             // can't find it
        }
        else                          // divide range
        {
            if (a[curIn].compareTo(searchKey) < 0)
            {
                return recFind(searchKey, curIn + 1, upperBound);
            }
            else                       // it's in lower half
            {
                return recFind(searchKey, lowerBound, curIn - 1);
            }
        }  // end else divide range
    }  // end recFind()

    public void insert(String value)    // put element into array
    {
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < nElems; j++)        // find where it goes
        {
            if (a[j].compareTo(value) > 0)            // (linear search)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        for (int k = nElems; k > j; k--)    // move bigger ones up
        {
            a[k] = a[k - 1];
        }
        a[j] = value;                  // insert it
        nElems++;                      // increment size
    }  // end insert()

    public void display()             // displays array contents
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < nElems; j++)       // for each element,
        {
            System.out.print(a[j] + " ");  // display it
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}  // end class OrdArray

class BinarySearchWordApp
{

    static final String AB = "12345aqwertyjklzxcvbnm";
    static Random rnd = new Random();

    public static String randomString(int len)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            sb.append(AB.charAt(rnd.nextInt(AB.length())));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int maxSize = 100000;             // array size
        SortedWordArray arr;                  // reference to array
        int[] indices = new int[27];
        arr = new SortedWordArray(maxSize);   // create the array

        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            arr.insert(randomString(10));   //insert it into the array
        }

        arr.display();                 // display array
        String searchKey;
        for (int i = 97; i < 124; i++)
        {
            searchKey = (i == 123)?"1":Character.toString((char) i);

            long time_1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            int result = arr.find(searchKey);
            long time_2 = System.currentTimeMillis() - time_1;
            if (result != -1)
            {
                indices[i - 97] = result;
                System.out.println("Found " + result + "in "+ time_2 +" ms");
            }
            else
            {
                if (!(i == 97))
                {
                    indices[i - 97] = indices[i - 97 - 1];
                }

                System.out.println("Can't find " + searchKey);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < indices.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Index [" + i + "][" + (char)(i+97)+"] = " + indices[i]);
        }
    }  // end main()

}
```

All comments welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this little piece of code will help you. I guessed the question is related to Java, because you mentioned ArrayList.

```
String[] unsorted = {"eve", "bob", "adam", "mike", "monica", "Mia", "marta", "pete", "Sandra"};
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(unsorted));

    String letter = "M"; // find index of this

     class MyComp implements Comparator<String>{
        String first = "";
        String letter;

        MyComp(String letter){
            this.letter = letter.toUpperCase();
        }

        public String getFirst(){
            return first;
        }

        @Override
        public int compare(String s0, String s1) {

            if(s0.toUpperCase().startsWith(letter)){
                if(s0.compareTo(first) == -1 || first.equals("")){
                    first = s0;
                }
            }

            return s0.toUpperCase().compareTo(s1.toUpperCase());
        }

    };

    MyComp mc = new MyComp(letter);

    Collections.sort(names, mc);

    int index = names.indexOf(mc.getFirst()); // the index of first name starting with letter
```

I'm not sure if it's possible to also store the index of the first name in the comparator without much overhead. Anyway, if you implement your own version of sorting algorithm e.g. quicksort, you should know about the index of the elements and could calculate the index while sorting. This depends on your chosen sorting algorithm and implementation. In fact if I know how your sorting is implemented, we could insert the index calculation.